# Wordpress Media Delete Logs

Tags: media-library

Is their a way to log when all media files get deleted? all user interaction and programmatically? I'm creating a Media Plugin logs for media that get deleted Or maybe a Hook of media delete.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look there is a dedicated `delete_attachment` action in `wp_delete_attachment()` function, it gets passed an ID of attachment being deleted.

However I am not completely confident that this covers *all* cases. There is a fair amount of duplication in WP's post–related APIs and similar tasks might be performed by different functions in different places.

I would start with this hook and experimentally check if it's sufficient for desired scenarios.